# wrong advice on duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, link-only-answers

I (probably) gave a New Contributor incorrect advice on duplicate questions.

The New Contributor found a question asked "yesterday" and posted a very good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824533/

He then a found the same question from like 6 months ago and posted an answer that is essentially just a link to his previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52842077/

I came across these in the order that he answered them, and posted a comment that he should have just flagged the second question as a duplicate. He did. The asker of the flagged question replied with: my question is 6 months old, the duplicate is from yesterday!

What should have been my advice?

"Copy-paste your answer from the new question to the old question and flag the new one as duplicate of the old", seems like a lot of work, and any upvotes would not carry over.

Comment: Well, I guess that only addresses part of the question, though, so maybe not a duplicate. But the other asker's comment about their question being older is irrelevant.

Comment: @Don'tPanic From the dup: "If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one." Plus your comment: "the other asker's comment about their question being older is irrelevant." pretty much answer my question completely. Thanx!